# Page automatically refreshing on AngularJS for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my app, the page periodically refreshes itself whenever I click a link that loads a different partial via the $routeprovider. Then, in addition to refreshing, it takes me back to the default partial (i.e., I'd have to click the link again in order to get where I wanted to go). I'm not using any methods that refresh the page at all; why might this be happening?

Also, interestingly enough, this doesn't happen when I click any non-$routeprovider links. The following is my routeProvider:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: "index.html"
            }).
            when('/profile/:id', {
                templateUrl: "profile.html",
                controller: 'UsersController as profiledUser'
            }).
            when('/gift/:id', {
                templateUrl: "gift.html",
                controller: 'GiftsController as profiledGift'
            }).
            when('/users-form', {
                templateUrl: "users-form.html",
                controller: 'UsersController as newUser'
            }).
            when('/login-form', {
                templateUrl: "login-form.html",
                controller: 'UsersController as loginUser'
            }).
            when('/gifts-form', {
                templateUrl: "gift-form.html",
                controller: 'GiftsController as newGift'
            }).
            when('/about', {
                templateUrl: "about.html"
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
```

Here's an example of one of the links, which links to the currently logged in user's profile, when inspected in Chrome's dev tool:

```
<a href="#profile/5" data-ng-click="template=1" style="color: white;">Profile</a>
```

Here's that same link in the code, where it's part of a navbar:

```
<li><a href="#profile/{{id}}" data-ng-click="template=1" style="color: white;">Profile</a></li>
```

To reiterate, clicking any of the above links occasionally both redirects to .otherwise and refreshes the page. I have not been able to reliably reproduce this behavior, as it seems to happen randomly; strangely enough, it happens even if I remove the .otherwise route from the config.

Comment: What browser and version?

Comment: Browser is Chrome, and Angular is v1.3.1.

Comment: Can you include more information?  Maybe show how the offending route is set up, and how the link html looks both in the source html and when you inspect it in chrome.

Comment: I wonder if changing your links to `<a ng-href="/profile/{{id}}"  ... > ... </a>` would make a difference?

Comment: The issue still happens with ng-href, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do 2 things at once with the click on the `<a>` tag but only 1 is happening:

1. The default action, which is in the href and says "load UsersController + profile view" and
2. set `template=1` in the current context

Even if `template=1` has occurred, once you switch to the UsersController you no longer have access to this setting.

Try something like this:

```
<a href="#/profile/{{id}}/{{template}}">Profile</a>
```

plus

```
.when('/profile/:id/:template', {
  controller: 'UsersController as profiledUser',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
```

Or, use $rootScope or some other global context for the `template=1` so it's always available to any controller+view as long as you've dependency injected it.